# Migrate localStorage data from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: javascript, https, local-storage, hsts

I've made a web app that stores persistent user data in `localStorage`. I've enabled HTTPS on my site, and I'd really like to flip the switch on HSTS. However, as far as I can tell, `localStorage` considers http://example.com and https://example.com to be different, so if existing users are redirected to the HTTPS version of my site, they can no longer access their data (though it still exists).

Long term, I want to build a new version of this app that offers more options for data storage. But in the short term, all I can think of is having a transition period where users at the http version are asked to migrate their data via some other (unknown) mechanism that both versions can access.

Is this a fair assessment of my options? Is there a way for https://example.com to access the `localStorage` of http://example.com? If not, is there anywhere I can put user data such that both versions can access it but other sites can't? Or should I ask them to download their data and re-upload it? That doesn't see ideal from a UX or (user) security standpoint.

Note that this web app doesn't interact with a server at all; everything happens with `localStorage` and the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be any way to directly retrieve localStorage contents for the less secure http copy of the site from the https site. [reference](http://htmlui.com/blog/2011-08-23-5-obscure-facts-about-html5-localstorage.html)

The workaround I have seen is to use an iframe loading a special page on the insecure site similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001387/share-dom-storage-between-http-and-https#answer-34301897). The general theory is to have code in the iframe that sends messages using `postMessage` with localStorage data back to the secure page.

Unfortunately this approach does not allow you to disable `http` entirely, because otherwise your iframed http copy would not load.

Comment: Mmmm, yeah. It seems like I could keep HSTS off for a while, hide the usual interface for HTTP users and have a button for them to populate HTTPS storage this way before transferring over with an 'update your bookmarks' sort of deal. Thanks!