# HTTP pages are removing my secure cookies

Tags: security, session, cookies, https, session-cookies

I have a site with mixed HTTP / HTTPS.  When the user logs in, she gets two cookies:

- a regular cookie with her (signed) username, login expire time, and an "insecure" flag
- a secure cookie with her (signed) username, login expire time, and a "secure" flag

  - note that if you don't have the secure/insecure flag within the signed content, an attacker can intercept the regular cookie and then send it as the secure one (my first implementation made this mistake)

I use the regular cookie on HTTP pages (just for showing her name while she browses the marketing portion of the site).  Then I use the secure cookie when she's on HTTPS pages (any user-specific pages).

I got the idea from [Secure cookies and mixed https/http site usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709085/secure-cookies-and-mixed-https-http-site-usage).

Everything works great, except that when the user navigates from an HTTPS page to an HTTP one, all of the secure cookies get deleted - which means that they can't go back to HTTPS pages after visiting even a single HTTP page.  I should mention that there is a "301 Moved Permanently" that redirects the user to from HTTPS to HTTP.

My site isn't clearing the secure cookie.  I know that the browser shouldn't send me the secure cookie while the user is looking at an HTTP site, but I expected the cookie to stick around for its lifetime, and get sent if the user ends up on an HTTPS page again.

I'm getting this same behavior on Chrome, Firefox, and IE.  Any tips?  I hope this isn't the expected behavior...

Comment: It may be a stupid question, but why mix http and https in the first place ? Why not use https on all your site ?

Comment: Do the cookies have different names?

Comment: Definitely a valid question!  The site has a lot of marketing and documentation.  You could easily put it all under https, and that'd be fine.  Except now your URLs look like "secure.domain.com" instead of "www.domain.com".  And the documentation and whatsuch is sorta loose (commenting and whatnot).  Whereas the user pages are pretty sensitive operations.  I want the user to know that they're in "www-land" or "secure-land".  And I'm too poor to buy another SSL cert ;-)

Comment: The cookies do have different names, e.g. "cookie_secure", "cookie_regular".  They do both have the same path "/", but that should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welp, that's embarassing.  Here's what my problem turned out to be.

- When the user tried to visit an HTTPS site from an HTTP one, their request would start as HTTP
- I would check their login credentials (which would fail, because the secure cookie wasn't there), *then* redirect them to HTTPS.  My "require login" and "require HTTPS" systems were separate (a bad design now, but it was convenient in the bad old days where the login cookie wasn't secure)
- I thought my secure cookie was being deleted because the Chrome cookie browser doesn't show secure cookies when the page being shown is HTTP.  The cookies were there all along.

Comment: 'Fraid so.  Unless maybe you're having the same mental glitch that I had.