# Fetch does not send Cookies with SameSite=None and Secure to an HTTPS page

Tags: javascript, cookies, https, fetch

I have the following setup:

- My backend server running on https://backend.com/api
- My web app running on http://127.0.0.1/login
- The browser has a Cookie:

  - SameSite: none
  - Secure
  - Domain: backend.com
  - Path: /
  - And a value of course

When trying to make a request to the backend from my web app no cookies are sent.

```
let response = await fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
})
```

What am I missing?

The following thread has given me a hint, which I am not sure if is the problem:
[HTTP pages are removing my secure cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734090/http-pages-are-removing-my-secure-cookies)

> When the user tried to visit an HTTPS site from an HTTP one, their request would start as an HTTP